# sumo taxi does not picks the right number of passengers

Tags: sumo

I'm fairly new using SUMO and traci tools.

I should have group of 4 persons boarding a taxi at the same time and going to the same destination.

for convenience, they are all waiting at the same place, in the same bus stop.

what happen :

When the taxi arrives, from time to time, only 2 or 3 persons board the taxi, then the taxi leaves and comes back to pickup the last persons before really starting the trip.

but for some other times, the taxi picks up the 4 persons and go for the trip as expected.

have you ever experience this behavior? why is it so?

Thanks,

br

Answer (score 0):

here is the way I solve the issue, it is surely not the best clean way to do it, but for now, it is sufficient to me. I post this answer because possibly it will help or give some hint to other people with similar issues.

I've managed to align my 4 people at the busstop, by acting on some parameters of this busstop, then I've computed the exact position for the first person, and I've managed to stop the taxi at this exact position.

as people are in line, they all enter the car at the same position.

The taxi does not need to realign itself on the next person.

this is quite bad, but it works for now.